# Git push over HTTP asking for password twice

Tags: git

I managed to make git work for pull and push over http. Now the last step it getting around the git push asking twice for my password. I don't want to use the .netrc file. any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

***Update:*** There's a better solution in git now, which I described in answer to this other question:

- [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/223092)

I've kept the old answer I wrote below for reference.

---

If you don't want to use `.netrc`, another option is to specify your username and password in the URL that your remote refers to, e.g. if your `origin` remote is:

```
http://some.server/whatever.git
```

... you could change it to `http://myusername:mypassword@some.server/whatever.git` with the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin http://myusername:mypassword@some.server/whatever.git
```

... and you won't need to enter your password manually.  This does mean that your password will be stored in plain text in your `.git/config` file, however.  If this is a problem, you're better off using public key based authentication with SSH.

Answer (score 2):

What about you make an ssh connection without password to the git server?
[Ssh connection without password](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)